# Android Studio Twitter search using twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to make an android studio program that searches twitter. I am using Twitter4J to write the code. I thought I had the code correct but right now the app crashes as soon as it loads. Here is the code.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


import twitter4j.Query;
import twitter4j.QueryResult;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




TextView tweetDisplay =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tweettext);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button Buffalo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BuffaloButton);
    Buffalo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey("Mykey")

                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret("my secret")
                    .setOAuthAccessToken("token")
                    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("my token sercert");

            Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
            try {
                Query query = new Query("#Buffaloriver");
                QueryResult result;
                result = twitter.search(query);
                for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
                    tweetDisplay.setText("@" + 
status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());

                }
            }
            catch(TwitterException e){
                tweetDisplay.setText(R.string.Oops);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


};
```

I have all my keys added in, and I have the internet access turned on in the manifest. I do not know what I am doing wrong with this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You initialized the **tweetDisplay** object at wrong place. It should be under **onCreate**  methode after setContentview called

Comment: Ok fixed that and now when I click the button it just crashes.

Comment: 11-24 21:03:44.037 11861-11861/jlfletcher.cpsc4367.ualr.edu.finalproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                           Process: jlfletcher.cpsc4367.ualr.edu.finalproject, PID: 11861
                                                                                           android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Ok , now the problem is u are doing network operation on main thread . That's why it is crashing . Use Asynctask to load your twitter APIs. You can find lots of tutorial for Asynctask task implementation. What ever code written in button click must either be moved to Asynctask or other thread